# PR_END_DATE < PR_START_DATE

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, mapi

During some work with MAPI I found very strange results for a few appointments, for example:

Tag: 0x00600040
Type: PT_SYSTIME
Property Name(s): PR_START_DATE, PidTagStartDate
DASL: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00600040
12:00:00 01.11.2012

Tag: 0x00610040
Type: PT_SYSTIME
Property Name(s): PR_END_DATE, PidTagEndDate
DASL: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00610040
02:30:00 01.11.2012

where EndDate is less than StartDate or EndDate is just different from that is shown in outlook calendar.

Appointment and Meeting Object Protocol Specification says that PidTagEndDate contains date and time of the appointment's end. But it seems that sometimes it contains length (2:30 in the example above). The most embarrasing thing about this is that Outlook shows dates correctly in calendars, so I need some way to interpret dates obtained from MAPI correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the reason but in my case PidTagEndDate (PR_END_DATE) is not correct on some appointments, in order to get right value one have to use other canonical property (if exists of course - it's not always set) [PidLidAppointmentEndWhole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815864.aspx) to which according to specification PidTagEndDate MUST be equal but it seems not always true at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try do it like this

```
LPSPropTagArray lppPropTags;
ULONG ulPropCount;
LPSPropValue pProp;
SYSTEMTIME& tmEnd;


HRESULT hr=m_appointment->GetProps(lppPropTags, MAPI_UNICODE, &ulPropCount, &pProp);
MAPIFreeBuffer(lppPropTags);

FILETIME tmLocal;
FileTimeToLocalFileTime(&pProp->Value.ft, &tmLocal);
FileTimeToSystemTime(&tmLocal, &tmStart);
```

tmLocal variable will contain end time

Comment: So you think that's just timezone (UTC->local) issue, but futher research shows that effective timezones set in PidLidAppointmentTimeZoneDefinitionStartDisplay and PidLidAppointmentTimeZoneDefinitionEndDisplay are identical. So StartDate MUST (and according to specification too) be less or equal to EndDate, but the reality is cruel :)

Comment: Do the value in pProp->Value.ft has the same value as PR_END_DATE?

Comment: Do you see other date/time props with the right date in OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI?

Comment: I saw end date in
 "h ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/820E0040"

Comment: And in this properties

h ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82360040
,
h ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/85170040

Comment: So, I found the problem:  despite the specification says that PidTagEndDate MUST be equal to PidLidAppointmentEndWhole they were somehow different and Outlook used PidLidAppointmentEndWhole which gives right value. Not sure whos to blame broken exchange storage or smthg else but now I get correct dates.